# Need to update one row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an application and need to update only one row in my database. The way I build the application it updates all my rows in the database. Could someone look in my script and tell me how i can update one row?

I know i need to do something with id's but i dont know how..

Here is the script for the page where users can change the data from the database. In this way every record will update.

```
        <section>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT naam, plaats.plaats, type.type, status FROM devices, type, plaats, status 
                    WHERE devices.type_id = type.type_id 
                    AND plaats.plaats_id = devices.plaats_id
                    AND status.status_id = devices.status_id
                    AND plaats.plaats ='benedenverdieping'";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo '<table><tr><td>Naam</td><td>Plaats</td><td>Type</td><td>Status</td><td>open/dicht</td><td>Submit</td></tr>';

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['naam']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['plaats']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['type']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['status']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>';?>
                            <form action="opendicht.php" method="post">
                                <select name="opendicht">
                                    <option name="open" value="1">open</option>
                                    <option name="dicht" value="2">dicht</option>
                                </select>
                        <?php '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'?>
                                <input type="submit" value="Doorvoeren" name="submit">
                            </form>                             
                        <?php '</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';                        
                }
        ?>
    </section>
```

Here is the script which execute the users input. Because of the sql query's it wont work for only one record. The way it works right now is the query updates every record with status_id 1 or 2. In the database the 1 stands for open and the 2 stands for closed. I can't find a way to let the query update only one row of data.

```
<?php
session_start();
$naam = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $naam;

include '../dbconnect.php';

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
$t=time();
$aanpassing = date("d-m-y h:i",$t);

$sel_device_id = ("SELECT device_id FROM devices");
$run_device_id = mysqli_query($con, $sel_device_id);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
        $opendicht = $_POST['opendicht'];
        if($opendicht =='1')
        {
            //UPDATE devices SET status_id = $opendicht, username = (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$naam'), timestamp = '$timestamp' WHERE status_id = '2'
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE devices SET status_id = $opendicht, username = '$naam', tijd = '$aanpassing' WHERE status_id = 2");
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE devices SET status_id = $opendicht, username = '$naam', tijd = '$aanpassing' WHERE status_id = 1");
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "er is iets fout gegaan";
    }

    mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection with Server
    header( "refresh:0;url=index.php" );
?>
```

Comment: fetch id of devices table in first script, and use the value as hidden field in your form. Then in second script you can update based on id

Comment: Could  you tell me how i could do that? Can't find a way to fetch the device_id

Answer (score 1):

These are your `UPDATE` queries:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE devices SET status_id = $opendicht, username = '$naam', tijd = '$aanpassing' WHERE status_id = 1");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE devices SET status_id = $opendicht, username = '$naam', tijd = '$aanpassing' WHERE status_id = 2");
```

You're updating all the rows where the `status_id` is `1` or `2`.

You need to add an `AND` condition to identify the unique row identifier to update.

Comment: From what I can make out, the unique identifier would be the `device_id` field. It needs to be added to the html form as well, probably as a hidden input, and then it can be read from `$_POST` when updating.

Comment: Could you please help me out. I don't know how i could make the form the way i can read the data out..